# How to make text overflow horizontally (stay on same line)

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble making a table cell to scroll horizontally. here's what I have so far

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>01/01/14</td>
    <td>
      <div class="scroll">
        A really long text that will overflow horizontally
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

And the scroll css

```
.scroll{ 
    height: 20px
    max-width: 500px
    overflow-x: scroll
    overflow-y: hidden
 }
```

Now no matter what I try, the cell will not overflow horizontally. It does vertically but is not what I want. Any ideas why this is not working?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're missing the semi-colon `;` at the end of your style rules. Also, add `white-space: nowrap` so that everything will stay on one line and continue to the right.

**[Live demo (click).](http://jsfiddle.net/BXk2v/)**

```
.scroll { 
    height: 20px;
    max-width: 500px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
 }
```

In my demo, I changed the `height` to `40px`. `20px` seems to small to see the text. You probably don't need `overflow-y`.

Comment: white-space: nowrap; is the key to get horizontal scrolling. Thanks a lot